подсказки для Nunjucks и Html
Доброй ночки всем, делаю проектик на express js, и вместо ejs решил использовать Nunjucks, у него есть блоки, которые очень упрощают жизнь, но в один момент понял, что с расширением prettier и beautify css становится неудобно его читать, ибо nunjucs'овский код не определяется и подсказок нет (файл с расширением html). Если установить Nunjucks снипеты то прекращаются снипеты для написания html, А ТЕПЕРЬ ВОПРОС, КАК СДЕЛАТЬ ТАК ЧТОБЫ ПОДСКАЗКИ ДЛЯ ДВУХ ЯЗЫКОВ РАБОТАЛИ В ОДНОМ ФАЙЛЕ И prettier ИХ НОРМАЛЬНО ОБРАБАТЫВАЛ?

заранее спасибо и удачи =)
